# How to remove a specific line in a file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have to make an app that edits a todo list (file to_do.txt). I can read it and also I can add new tasks, but I cannot remove a specific line of the file without destroying everything. How can I do it? This is my code

```
 program compito4
        implicit none
        
        ! Declaring the variables
        integer :: unit, stat, counter, i
        character (len = 1) action
        character (len = 200) line, new_task
    
    
        ! Open the program
    
        open(newunit = unit, file = 'to_do.txt', status = 'OLD', position = 'APPEND')
        do
            print *, 'What would you like to do? (a)dd, (d)elete, (l)ist, (q)uit'
            read (*,*) action
            if (action == 'a') then
                print *, 'Insert the new task'
                read (*, '(A)') new_task
                write (unit, '(A)') '\n' // new_task    ! // is the string concatenation operator
                print *, 'New task successfully added'
            else if (action == 'd') then
                print *, 'Insert the number of the task to be removed'
                read (*,*) i
                print *, i
                counter = 0
                rewind unit
                do
                    read(unit, '(A)', iostat = stat) line
                    if (stat .ne. 0) then
                        backspace unit
                        exit
                    
                    else if (i == counter) then
                        print *, 'You are in the right spot'
                        print *, counter
                        backspace unit
                        write (unit, '(2A)') trim(line), ('->Task done')
                    end if
                    counter = counter + 1
                end do
            else if (action == 'l') then
                rewind unit
                counter = 0
                do
                    read(unit, '(A)', iostat = stat) line
                    if (stat .ne. 0) then        ! It handles the end of file!
                        backspace unit
                        exit
                    end if
                    print *, counter,') ', line
                    counter = counter + 1
            
                end do
            else if (action == 'q') then
                print *, 'Closing the program'
                exit
            else
                print *, 'Invalid choice'
            end if
        end do
    
        close(unit)
        
    
        
    end program compito4
```

Comment: The file mode is set to `append` which means you can only append to existing file.

Comment: The append mode serves me to add things at the end of the file. Is there a method to retain the mode and remove a selected line inside the file?

Comment: What about the dirty-and-quick method: reading the file into memory, and writing it back into the file except for the specific line?

Comment: @jack - that would have been my second comment. The _op_ does not have a in-memory representation of the file contents either as a string, or parsed as a an array of strings.